# Tkinter checkbox not updating when paired with "if" function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a small code that allows you to create a line graph which has different plots on it depending on if or not a checkbox is ticked. The code currently looks like the one below, however ticking or not ticking the checkboxes does not seem to effect the graph each time it runs.

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

master = Tk()

cb1 = StringVar()
cb2 = StringVar()
fig = plt.figure()

def graph():
    df = pd.read_excel (r'C:/Users/joshp/OneDrive - University of Strathclyde/Josh PhD/Interviews/Information for MACIDs/GEMaP Practise/Utilities.xlsx', index_col='PT: TD: BP')
    if cb1 == 'on':
        ax=df.iloc[0:1].T.plot()
        df.iloc[2:3].T.plot(ax=ax)
    else:
        ax=df.iloc[0:1].T.plot()
        
    if cb2 == 'on':
        df.iloc[5:6].T.plot(ax=ax)
    plt.show()
        
  
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=master)
plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
plot_widget.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
c1 = Checkbutton(master, text='option1', variable = cb1, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
c1.grid(row=9, column=2)
c2 = Checkbutton(master, text='option2', variable = cb2, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
c2.grid(row=8, column=2)


    
    
button3 = Button(master, text='Show utilies', command=graph)
button3.grid(row=9, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=40, pady=10)


mainloop()
```

Ignoring the checkboxes and simply putting `x` or `y` for the `if` functions produces the expected results.

Comment: Your `StringVar`s will *never* be equal to 'on'.  They might perhaps contain the value 'on', but you have to call `.get()` on the `StringVar` to retrieve that value.

Comment: You need to initialize your `Stringvar`s to either `'on'` or `'off'` using something like `cb1 = StringVar(value='on')` and check their current values via their `get()` methods like this: `if cb1.get() == 'on':`.

Comment: @martineau cheers that seems to have got it working.I made all stringvars `cb1 = StringVar(value='on')`  I then changed the if to what you suggsted, this worked for the original code but when pasted into my larger GUI it stopped working and it acted like all the checkboxes are always on.

Comment: Josh: That's good to hear. Many don't know about the `value=` keyword argument — now you're not one of them. ;¬)

Comment: The problems when "pasted into my larger GUI" sound like you're calling `Tk()` more than once.  You need to use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: @jasonharper sorry I should of mentoined I fixed this, I had a graph being produced in an earlier section of code for another reason before I started the Tkinter, moving that into the tkinter seemed to fix it, although im not sure why.